# Simple Merge Sort in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have been doing a small revision of sorting algorithms and came across with Merge Sort. I have written my code and have been modifying it for the last hour determining why it is not still working. I am getting standard StackOverFlow Exception. Can anyone advise me what's wrong with the algorithm? Thanks in advance. Here what I have managed to write so far:

```
public Int32[] MergeSort(Int32[] array)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (array.Length == 0) { return array; }
    int mid = array.Length / 2;
    Int32[] leftHalf = new Int32[mid+1];
    Int32[] rightHalf = new Int32[mid+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        leftHalf[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (int j = mid; j < array.Length; j++) {
        rightHalf[counter] = array[j];
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    MergeSort(leftHalf);
    MergeSort(rightHalf);
    return SortAndMerge(leftHalf,rightHalf);
}

public Int32[] SortAndMerge(Int32[] left, Int32[] right) {
    Int32[] myResult = new Int32[left.Length+right.Length];
    while (left.Length > 0 || right.Length > 0) {
        if (left.Length > 0 && right.Length > 0)
        {
            if (left[0] <= right[0])
            {
                myResult[myResult.Length] = left[0];
                int toRemoveIndex = Array.IndexOf(left, left[0]);
                left = left.Where((x, y) => y != toRemoveIndex).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                myResult[myResult.Length] = right[0];
                int toRemoveIndex = Array.IndexOf(right, right[0]);
                right = right.Where((z, g) => g != toRemoveIndex).ToArray();
            }

        }
        else if (left.Length > 0)
        {
            myResult[myResult.Length] = left[0];
            int toRemoveIndex = Array.IndexOf(left, left[0]);
            left = left.Where((x, y) => y != toRemoveIndex).ToArray();
        }
        else if (right.Length > 0) {
            myResult[myResult.Length] = right[0];
            int toRemoveIndex = Array.IndexOf(right, right[0]);
            right = right.Where((x, y) => y != toRemoveIndex).ToArray();
        }
    }
    return myResult;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `counter` is doing in the `MergeSort` function?...I mean I know what it is accomplishing, but why not use `rightHalf[j - mid]` instead of `rightHalf[counter]`...might make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry to ask Rustam, but using so many nested if's, is it really required? Before even looking why there is an SO error, should we look into getting rid of these nested if's, as part of my revision of algorithms I am going to see if algorithms did indeed require such hideosities.

Comment: The debugger will give you a stack trace and you can go through the code line by line. That would give you a lot of information on what's happening, especially on eternal loops.

Comment: Stack Overflow in these contexts usually means "infinite recursion". Check your boundary conditions.

Comment: @DomFarolino in order to append to rightHalf I am using a counter as an index rightHalf[0], rightHalf[1] etc. [j-mid] will not give you a natural sequence from 0++;

Comment: @Arjang Thank you for your valuable advice, I wrote this algorithm as I imagined it in my head :) Since now, I will work on improving it.

Comment: @GabeMoothart I am feeling myself weak in situations with recursions, would you suggest any answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RustamUmarov how will `j - mid` not give you a natural sequence? `j` starts at `mid` and then goes up by one making `j - mid` equal to `0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: @DomFarolino sorry I got it in a wrong way. I will optimize it right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (array.Length == 0) return;
```

This is never true, thus the exception, because you always create array like this.

```
Int32[] leftHalf = new Int32[mid+1];
```

The minimum length is 1.

Check out correct merge sort algorithm here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind refactoring? Why not use [zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx)
Here the sample from msdn

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

This code produces the following output:

1 one

2 two

3 three

There is also linq for sort.

Comment: I am considering implementation of merge sort, that is why ZIP will not work for me. Anyway, thanks.